# Is Scipy's distance.cdist function only single thread or is it possible to make it multithread?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, scipy

Is Scipy's distance.cdist function only single thread or is it possible to make it multithread?

I have tested it on my computer with very large matrices on both sides ((1000000,100) and (10, 100)) and only one of the CPU is used. My setting as follows, which shows that I have BLAS installed:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__config__.show()
openblas_info:
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
    libraries = ['openblas']
openblas_lapack_info:
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
    libraries = ['openblas']
blas_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
    libraries = ['openblas']
lapack_opt_info:
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = f77
    libraries = ['openblas']
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

Comment: I suppose this is depending on the metric (and of course your BLAS-setup). Check if your openblas was compiled with openmp (or just do your by-eye check with some big matrix-multiplication). Then reason about your metric. Apart from some more complex algorithms in linear-algebra (LAPACK and co.) not much is parallel besides ```numpy.dot```. The latter is used in metric ```sqeuclidean``` for example and you should see the effects. Other metrics like ```cosine``` do not look parallel to me.